# Jekyll, Markdown not rendering content in the normal way (top to bottom), but instead all to the right

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, jekyll

[image]

My Markdown (with front matter) is this:

```
---
layout: post
title:  "Facultad de Lenguas y Letras"
date:   2018-01-18 24:00:00 -0600
categories: animacion
permalink: facultad-de-lenguas-y-letras-i
thumbnail: https://dl.dropbox.com/s/4ou7ndl36vxdaa0/facultad.gif?raw=1
---

<h2 class="fuente-fjalla-titulo">Geosmina - Facultad de Lenguas y Letras I</h2>

(youtube video with markdown format)

Hola.
```

My post layout is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

{%include head.html%}

<body>
    <!-- Imagen header que dice Animanoir -->
    {%include header.html%}

    <!-- El sidebar y el contenido  -->
    {%include sidebar-main-post.html%}

    <!-- Footer normal -->
    {%include footer.html%}

    <!-- El jQuery de Bootstrap 4.0.0beta -->
    {%include js.html%}

    {%include hogarjq.html%}

</body>

</html>
```

And this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <nav class="col-sm-3 ">
      <div class="col-sm-12" id="fixed-sidebar">
        <!-- <a href="index.html"><img id="home-logo" src="../../media/logo-prueba.jpg" alt="Logo de Animanoir"> </a> -->
        <ul>
          <li class="fuente-fjalla ul-personalizada">Animación</li>
          <li class="fuente-fjalla ul-personalizada">Ilustración</li>
          <li class="fuente-fjalla ul-personalizada">Interacción</li>
          <br>
          <li class="fuente-fjalla ul-personalizada">Blog</li>
          <br>
          <li class="fuente-fjalla ul-personalizada">Acerca</li>
          <li class="fuente-fjalla ul-personalizada">Contacto</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="col-sm-9" id="main-content">

      <div class="row">

        <h2>{{ post.title }}</h2>

        {{content}}

    </div>

  </div>
|</div>
</div>
```

The CSS is this:

```
#main-content {
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Average', serif;
    font-size: 1em;
}
```

The rendered HTML is:

```
<body>
    <!-- Imagen header que dice Animanoir -->
    <header id="header-home">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
        <a href="home.html"><img id="header-logo" class="img-fluid" src="../media/animanoir-logo-blanco-chico.png" alt=""/> </a> 
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>

    <!-- El sidebar y el contenido  -->
    <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <nav class="col-sm-3 ">
      <div class="col-sm-12" id="fixed-sidebar">
        <!-- <a href="index.html"><img id="home-logo" src="../../media/logo-prueba.jpg" alt="Logo de Animanoir"> </a> -->
        <ul>
          <li class="fuente-fjalla ul-personalizada">Animación</li>
          <li class="fuente-fjalla ul-personalizada">Ilustración</li>
          <li class="fuente-fjalla ul-personalizada">Interacción</li>
          <br>
          <li class="fuente-fjalla ul-personalizada">Blog</li>
          <br>
          <li class="fuente-fjalla ul-personalizada">Acerca</li>
          <li class="fuente-fjalla ul-personalizada">Contacto</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="col-sm-9" id="main-content">

      <div class="row">

        <h2></h2>

        <h2 class="fuente-fjalla-titulo">Geosmina - Facultad de Lenguas y Letras I</h2>

<p><a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=be73Nr5HIss"><img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/be73Nr5HIss/0.jpg" alt="IMAGE ALT TEXT HERE" /></a></p>

<p>Hola.</p>


    </div>

  </div>
</div>
</div>

    <!-- Footer normal -->
    <!--footer-->
<footer>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
                <p id="copyrights">Animanoir 2018 &copy;</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
<!--fin de footer-->

    <!-- El jQuery de Bootstrap 4.0.0beta -->
    <!--Bootstrap jQuery-->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-a5N7Y/aK3qNeh15eJKGWxsqtnX/wWdSZSKp+81YjTmS15nvnvxKHuzaWwXHDli+4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script async src="js/hogarjq.js"></script>

</body>
```

I'm using **Bootstrap 4**.

I thought Markdown would render everything exactly as it is written, not trying to fill a row until it gets full, and then passing to the next one.

Comment: You can inspect the rendered HTML.

Comment: @Xlee Done. It looks exactly how it should look. Markdown rendering is the problem, or I dunno if the bootstrapping I'm doing.

Comment: You can remove the classes for debugging

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

Added *col-sm-12* to a div, and inside the content.

```
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <h2>{{ post.title }}</h2>
      {{content}}
    </div>
```